# How to get predefined property from sub-object?

Tags: typescript

This works as expected

```
const a = {
  b: {
    c: 2
  }
}
const propOf = <T, K extends keyof T, P extends keyof T[K]>(
    obj: T,
    key: K,
    p: P
) => obj[key][p]

const d = propOf(a, 'b', 'c')
```

It it makes it possible to extract the property `c`, but I am looking for a way to define a function that always extracts `c`

```
const propC = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) => obj[key].c
const e = propC(a, 'b')
```

This however gives me an error

> Property 'c' does not exist on type 'T[K]'

How should I write the `propC` function to get it to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More general case, where you don't know exact type of `c`, but you want to infer it, would be like this:

```js
const a = {
    b: {
        c: 2
    }
};
const b = {
    b: {
        c: "text"
    }
};

type TypeOfPropC<T> = T extends { [key: string]: { c: infer U } } ? U : unknown;
const propC = <T extends { [key: string]: { c: TypeOfPropC<T> } }, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) => obj[key].c;

const e = propC(a, 'b'); // e is `number`
const f = propC(b, 'b'); // f is `string`
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that `b` type contains the `c` property, why do not use a predefined type? For example:

```js
type A = {
  [key: string]: {
    c: number
  }
}

const a: A = {
  b: {
    c: 2
  }
};

// access c prop directly
const c1 = a['b'].c;

// or the generic version
const propC = <T extends A>( obj: T, key: keyof T ) => obj[key].c
const c2 = propC(a, 'b')
```

You cannot access the `c` property inside the generic function, because the function doesn't know anything about the T type. The type of the object `a` is unknown until you pass it to the function and it's unavailable for the function.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I was aiming for a generic version that with your input can be written as `const propC = <T extends { [key: string]: { c: number } }, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  key: K
) => obj[key].c`

Comment: You can write it even simpler: `const propC = <T extends { [key: string]: { c: number } }>( obj: T, key: keyof T ) => obj[key].c`